# Rebuild widgets when a subcollection recieves data in another widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have 6 widgets that all share the same data with only one receiving the data from the stream

AllClasses() //displays all of classes and is the start of getting the data from the stream

ClassList(data) //displays nothing but builds the list view and holds the index of what class is to be displayed in classtile widget

ClassTile(data) //presents the data from the index of the data passed in from ClassList

ClassPage(data) //when a classtile is clicked this screen is presented

HomeworksList(data)  //goes to this widget when the homeworks button is clicked shows all the homeworks that are available for the specific class clicked on

HomeworkTile(data) // shows the tile for each homework

As you can see I get the data once then pass it down the widget tree multiple times. What has become an issue is that when I am showing the homework list which is 5 widgets down the widget tree from where the data is coming from I have the option to add another homework to the homework list. technically adding it to the firestore database.

The problem is that when I add a Homework it does not refresh the data or rebuild any widgets until I go all the way back to the "AllClasses()" widget.

so to reiterate, I have a widget that shows all of the homeworks and in this widget you are able to add a homework and when you do it updates the subcollection, but does not rebuild the widget that shows all of the homeworks until I go back a couple widgets from where the data is first grabbed

the database schema is set up like this:

```
Classes {
  subcollections:
    Homework {
      ...

    }


  fields:




}
```

perhaps its the way I have my database and instead I should have a Homeworks collection that is outside of everything. or maybe its because I am using a generator future to produce the same thing as a stream by using a never ending while loop. either way I don't understand streams enough to understand what to do next, I have been working on this since 8am today and I have tried just about everything in my power. I may just use Homeworks as a seperate collection instead of a subcollection the problem with this is knowing which class I am in when I click on homework.

```
Stream<List<ClassData>> get fetchClassdata async* {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await classesCollection.getDocuments();

    // while (true) {
    List<ClassData> _classList = List<ClassData>();

    await Future.forEach(snapshot.documents, (element) async {
      QuerySnapshot pre = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("Classes")
          .document(element.documentID)
          .collection("Pre")
          .getDocuments();
      QuerySnapshot homeworksSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("Classes")
          .document(element.documentID)
          .collection("Homework")
          .getDocuments();

      QuerySnapshot notesSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("Classes")
          .document(element.documentID)
          .collection("Notes")
          .getDocuments();

      QuerySnapshot testsSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("Classes")
          .document(element.documentID)
          .collection("Tests")
          .getDocuments();

      List<Preq> _preList = List<Preq>();
      List<Homework> _homeworkList = List<Homework>();
      List<Note> _notesList = List<Note>();
      List<Test> _testsList = List<Test>();

      pre.documents.forEach((preClass) {
        Preq preqData = Preq.fromMap(preClass.data);

        if (preClass.data != null) {
          _preList.add(preqData);
        }
      });

      homeworksSnapshot.documents.forEach((hwork) {
        Homework homeworkdata = Homework.fromMap(hwork.data);

        _homeworkList.add(homeworkdata);
      });

      

      ClassData data = ClassData.fromMap(
          element.data, element.documentID, _preList, _homeworkList);

      if (data != null) {
        _classList.add(data);
      }
    });

    yield _classList;
    // }
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Any child widget will not be rebuilt if you are currently in the child widget. in order to get the functionality that I wanted I needed to declare the provider again in the widget that I wanted rebuilt when I received new data.